# Copy specific files recursively

Tags: linux, bash, find, cp

This problem has been discussed extensively but I couldn't find a solution that would help me.

I'm trying to selectively copy files from a directory tree into a specific folder. After reading some Q&A, here's what I tried:

```
cp `find . -name "*.pdf" -type f` ../collect/
```

I am in the right parent directory and there indeed is a `collect` directory a level above. Now I'm getting the error: **cp: invalid option -- 'o'**

What is going wrong?

Comment: Run the find command separately: do you have one or more files with spaces in their names? Perhaps like 'My name -o will be a problem if used naively.pdf' ... ?

Comment: You're right. There are all kinds of slashes, spaces and brackets in the folder structure, as these have been maintained by date. Any workaround?

Comment: @John1024 It copied only those files that had no spaces in their name. Can I do something to convert spaces into underscores and then retry?

Comment: @dotslash I just posted an answer that should work better.

Comment: @John1024 And I just accepted it. Giant "thank you" form my side! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle difficult file names:

```
find . -name "*.pdf" -type f -exec cp {} ../collect/ \;
```

By default, `find` will print the file names that it finds.  If one uses the `-exec` option, it will instead pass the file names on to a command of your choosing, in this case a `cp` command which is written as:

```
cp {} ../collect/ \;
```

The `{}` tells `find` where to insert the file name.  The end of the command given to `-exec` is marked by a semicolon.  Normally, the shell would eat the semicolon.  So, we escape the semicolon with a backslash so that it is passed as an argument to the `find` command.

Because `find` gives the file name to `cp` directly without interference from the shell, this approach works for even the most difficult file names.

#### More efficiency

The above runs `cp` on every file found.  If there are many files, that would be a lot of processes started.  If one has GNU tools, that can be avoided as follows:

```
find . -name '*.pdf' -type f -exec cp -t ../collect {} +
```

In this variant of the command, `find` will supply many file names for each single invocation of `cp`, potentially greatly reducing the number of processes that need to be started.

Comment: Works like a charm! Care to explain how it does the magic? :)

Comment: @dotslash Explanation added.  Let me if you have questions remaining.

Comment: Perfectly workable. Note that cp will be invoked once for each file found. Not a problem for dozens or hundreds of files, but sometimes providing more args to the invoked program, and invoking it far fewer times (say, ten thousand files), is a win. That's where `xargs` can be useful, eg: `find . -name '*.pdf' -type f -print0 | xargs -0 cp -t ../collect`

Comment: @sjnarv Good thought!  I added a version of that, but without `xargs`, to the answer.

Comment: @John1024 Awesome answer! Just one final thing: why does `find` need the semi-colon? I don't see it in other command-line tools/commands.

Comment: The `-exec` argument to `find(1)` can have many arguments; they're all concatenated to form a command to be run. You need to provide some indication that the command is done, and the normal way is a semicolon, which must be escaped if you're invoking `find` from a shell (i.e., `\;`). In common `find` usage, the `-exec` is often last, so the semi-colon feels a bit superfluous. But an `-exec` option can be followed by other predicates in the overall expression, which is why some syntax is needed to tell `find` that the command's spec is complete.

Comment: @dotslash "I don't see it in other command-line tools/commands."  Yes, as far as I know, it is unique to `find`. It is there, as sjnarv explains, to provide the flexibility to have multiple actions.